Call procedure with parameter from HTML template in TMS WEB Core
I have a simple project in TMS WEB Core.
I want to create a series of buttons at runtime in a loop inside of my TWebHTMLDiv component and call the Delphi myFunc function based on the loop index of each button.
The myFunc function on the Delphi side takes input and sends a ShowMessage with the button index.
My problem is that I don't know how to call a function with a parameter from the template side
My unit Code:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, JS, Web, WEBLib.Graphics, WEBLib.Controls,
  WEBLib.Forms, WEBLib.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls, WEBLib.WebCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TWebForm)
    WebHTMLDiv1: TWebHTMLDiv;
    procedure WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure myFunc(ACode: string);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.myFunc(ACode: string);
begin
  ShowMessage(ACode);
end;

procedure TForm1.WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := '';
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text +
      '<button type="button" onclick="myFunc(' + i.ToString +
      ')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BtnNum' + i.ToString + '</button>';
end;

end.

My HTML template Code:
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TMS Web Project</title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id = "htmlDiv">
  </div>
  </body>
</html>


@AmigoJack . no need this.... my question is about call procedure. do you work with TMS WEB CORE?

@AmigoJack The spaces doesn't matter in his HTML template example. id = "htmlDiv" is perfectly fine. In the output HTML, when you "inspect element" in the browser, you'll see it'll show as id="htmlDiv". The pas2js compiler removes the spaces.

"Inspect element" is the DOM which the browser rendered out of the source. Press Ctrl+U to see the actual source. However, I was wrong: HTML5 allows zero or multiple whitespaces around the equals sign.

Method 1
In your example, to call your Delphi myFunc procedure from JavaScript code, you can simply call the procedure like this in JavaScript:
pas.Unit1.TForm1.myFunc('1998');

And that would work. So your full WebFormShow code would be:
procedure TForm1.WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := '';
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text +
      '<button type="button" onclick="pas.Unit1.TForm1.myFunc(' + i.ToString +
      ')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BtnNum' + i.ToString + '</button>';
end;

Method 2
As an alternative method. You can also assign a click eventListener to each button.
I've modified the <button> to include a data_code attribute and added a MyBtnClick class to it. I then also modified your myFunc function to have a Sender: TJSEvent parameter.
Here's the full code:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, JS, Web, WEBLib.Graphics, WEBLib.Controls,
  WEBLib.Forms, WEBLib.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls, WEBLib.WebCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  WEBLib.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TWebForm)
    WebHTMLDiv1: TWebHTMLDiv;
    procedure WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure myFunc(Sender: TJSEvent);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.myFunc(Sender: TJSEvent);
var
  ACode: String;
begin
  ACode := Sender.targetElement.getAttribute('data_code');
  ShowMessage(ACode);
end;

procedure TForm1.WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  MyBtnClick: TJSHTMLCollection;
begin
  WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := '';
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text := WebHTMLDiv1.HTML.Text +
      '<button type="button" data_code="' + i.ToString +
      '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm MyBtnClick"' +
      '>BtnNum' + i.ToString + '</button>';


  MyBtnClick := document.getElementsByClassName('MyBtnClick');
  for I := 0 to MyBtnClick.length-1 do
  begin
    MyBtnClick.Items[I].addEventListener('click', @myFunc);
  end;
end;

end.


Greate... very big tnx bro... Method 2 is work fine.... very good.... method 1 have red error on screen.... god bless you...

Most likely because it then computes as myFunc(1) instead of myFunc('1') - your method expects a String, not an Integer.

@amigojack : Excelent... its ok... both way is true..... tnx
